# Writing Unit test for Angular6 directive

Tags: angular

I have a simple directive written in Angular6

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener} from '@angular/core';
    @Directive({
      selector: '[appClickOutside]'
    })
    export class ClickOutsideDirective {
      @Output('clickOutside') _clickOutside = new EventEmitter()

      constructor(private _elementRef : ElementRef) { 
      }

      @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
        public onClick(targetElement) {
            const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
            if (!clickedInside) {
                this._clickOutside.emit();

            }
        }

    }
```

This directive basically listen for click event outside the component and react accordingly.

i want to write Unit test for this directive.

I am trying but no idea how to do that. Can anyone please help.

This is the default spec.ts, with some addition:

```
import { ClickOutsideDirective } from './click-outside.directive';
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

describe('ClickOutsideDirective', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    //TODO: Just passing null as event to make this file compilable
    const directive = new ClickOutsideDirective(null);
    expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  });
});


export class MockElementRef extends ElementRef {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to test this Directive just like you would test a component, using [TestBed](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/TestBed). You have to place this directive on a [test host](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-inside-a-test-host) component with the following template:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div class="inside" appClickOutside (clickOutside)="onClickOutside()"></div>
    <div class="outside"></div>
  `
})
export class TestHostComponent {
  onClickOutside(): void {}
}
```

You can then create a TestBed:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ ClickOutsideDirective, TestHostComponent ]
})

const fixture  = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
const testHost = fixture.componentInstance;
const inside = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.inside');
const outside = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.outside');
```

You can then create a spy on the `onClickOutside` of your `TestHostComponent` and trigger clicks on the inside and outside element (I'm leaving that up to you to find out :)).

I guess this is more of an integration test than a unit test, but it makes more sense with a directive like this. Otherwise you have to mock a lot of stuff if you just want to test the `onClick` and that makes no sense in this case, in my opinion.